# Выпадающий блок при клике. jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Доброго времени суток. Заранее прошу прощения за такой вопрос. Но что добавить в [JS код](http://jsfiddle.net/BETEPAH/a4jLb9wL/), чтобы при клике на сам блок `#drop-down-list, .no-display, .drop-down-block` он не закрывался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так, но к сожалению пришлось не добавить в JS как вы просили, а подправить JS

```
$(document).on('click.fadeBlock', function(e){
        if($(e.target).closest('#toggler').length < 1 && $(e.target).closest('#drop-down-list').length < 1)
          block.fadeOut(opts['speed']);
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a4jLb9wL/5/

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все отлично.

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё решение. Можно текст разбить на две части  "комплексный бренд , осознав", и после "осознав" будет идти уже следующий блок. Это для того, что бы по нажатию была анимация выезжания блока и сдвига текста вниз.

Вот код, который будет отвечать за появление блока:

```
$('#yourClass').click(function() {
    $('#classOfWindow').slideToggle('300');
    $('#classOfWindow').toggleClass('.footer-contacts-window-active');
});

$('#yourClassClose').click(function() {
    $('#classOfWindow').slideToggle('300');
});
```